# rotate a image within background-blend-mode

Tags: css, background-blend-mode

I wonder if there is a possibility to rotate an image within background-blend-mode.
I want to rotate my second image:
 GLRlogo_RGB.png. I've tried it to transform, translate but it doesn't seem to work that way.
Can anyone help me with a solution? 
Thanks!

Here my code

```
#main-image-3{
        background-image: url(../img/layout-picture4.jpg), url(../img/GLRlogo_RGB.png);
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover, calc(15rem + 10vw);
        margin: 0 0 73rem 0;
        transform: rotate(0,0,45deg);
        }

        #main-image-1, #main-image-2, #main-image-3{
        background-color: rgba(9, 231, 9, 0.301);
        background-blend-mode: screen, multiply; 
    }
```

Comment: It's an empty element but you right. I found the right answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know to do that is by seting your background property to a pseudo element `::before` or `::after` then apply the rotation to it and hide what is overlapping with `overflow:hidden` like so

```css
.back-rotate {
  width:500px; /*it's important to have a size for the relative size of the ::before pseudo element*/
  height:200px;
  position:relative; /*also important, but if you don't use it, then set the ::before to 'relative' instead of 'absolute' and .back-rotate to 'static' */
  overflow:hidden;
}

.back-rotate::before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  /*positioning my background relatively to the main container*/
  width:200%;
  height:200%;
  top:-50%;
  left:-50%;
  /*layer position 0 so he get behind what the div contains (text etc) */
  z-index:0;
  
  /*the rotation*/
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
/* my background image */
.back-rotate::before {
  background-image:url('https://helpx.adobe.com/in/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/_jcr_content/main-pars/image.img.jpg/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_1000x560.jpg');
```

```html
<div class='back-rotate'></div>
```

Comment: @Sebastian Glad to hear, you can validate the answer if it's the good one ;) if someone get a better one you can change later

Comment: This works ;) It would be easier if you could select the second image within background-image and simply use tranform translate(45deg) on it. if you know what i mean :)

Comment: i did forget to ad the "background-blend-mode" part to my question. i've added it.

Comment: put your second image in a ::after (if you used ::before for the first one) and play around with it like the first one